# Groups Question

Tags: group-theory

Let a and b be elements of a group (G,*). Show that $(a*b)^2 = a^2 * b^2$ iff $a*b = b*a$

I'm trying to prove the iff statement from left to right first.
$$\begin{align}
(a*b)^2 &= a^2 *b^2   \\
a*b*a*b &= a*a*b*b    \\
b*a*b   &= a*b*b       \\
a*b     &= b^{-1} *a*b*b  
\end{align}$$

I got stuck after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finish the forward direction, starting from your third line:

$$b*a*b = a*b*b \iff b*a* b*b^{-1} = a*b*b*b^{-1} \iff b*a = a*b$$

Here, I've *right*-multiplied by $b^{-1}$ instead for left-multiplying, as you did.

Now, starting from the assumption $a*b = b*a$:

$$\begin{align} a * b = b*a & \iff a*a*b = a*b*a \\ \\ &\iff a*a*b*b= a*b*a*b \\ \\ &\iff a^2*b^2 = (a*b)^2\end{align}$$

Note that starting from either side of "if and only if", we essentially have biconditionals between each step, hence each direction is taken care of by either of the two chains of biconditionals.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I thought I couldn't right multiply, I guess because the rules weren't explained clearly to me.

Comment: The "rules" are the group axioms, there's not that many of them.

Comment: Which axiom would imply this rule? Is it associativity?